# How do I convert a geometry column from binary format to string format in a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, geospatial, geospark

Here is my attempt at this:

`%sql SELECT df1.*,df1.geometry.STAsText() as geom_text FROM df_geo df1.`

This obviously fails because it is not a table, but a dataframe. How can one do this using pyspark or geospark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use GeoSparkSQL,

```
SELECT *, ST_AsText(geometry) as geom_text FROM df_geo
```

In pyspark:

```
df_geo.createOrReplaceTempView("df_geo")
df2 = spark.sql("SELECT *, ST_AsText(geometry) as geom_text FROM df_geo")
```

Comment: df1 = df_geo.withColumn('geom_text', df_geo.geometry.STAsText())

TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Comment: @Mazil_tov998 I removed that. Try the SQL query?